# Struggling to make this tumblr theme filter code work, the buttons are there but aren't clickable

Tags: tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I'm working on a theme for my personal multi-muse blog on Tumblr (I write about 40 characters on a single blog). I'm combining two codes (or, well, using one code and adding an open-source filter due to the sheer number of muses on the blog), and each works independently. I think I've made them almost entirely compatible, but I'm struggling to get the filters on the sidebar to work: the buttons seem to exist, they hover appropriately and the filters exist in the code, but I can't actually get the buttons to be clickable. I can't figure out what's not working.It looks like it should work, from everything I see, but then it still doesn't work.

I've tried importing the body text from the theme I usually use the filter option on (to bring all possible issues to bear), but I haven't been able to make the buttons clickable. First I tried just the filter section and the div class for the containers to be filtered, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have a github for the code [here](https://github.com/LadyArgent/Tumblr-Theme-Works/blob/main/Filtered%20MultiMuse%20Theme) if anyone wants to peruse, credit given to the main theme still of course. I'm just trying to add to the base theme, not doctor it any further, but the code that filters appropriately elsewhere doesn't seem to be making the buttons properly.